# Most recent shipment SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do the same thing as is happening below. Essentially for a given shipment I need to find the most recent shipment of the same product. On small data it is not a huge issue but on a million plus rows it becomes an incredible time hog.

```
Create table #test(
ID int,
Product varchar(50),
DeliveryDate datetime
)

Insert into #test values
(1,'Apples','1/1/17'),
(2,'Oranges','1/1/17'),
(3,'Apples','2/1/17'),
(4,'Grapes','2/1/17'),
(5,'Apples','3/1/17'),
(6,'Grapes','3/1/17'),
(7,'Apples','4/1/17'),
(8,'Apples','5/1/17')


Select top 100 * From #test



SELECT 
T.Id,
T.Product,
T.DeliveryDate,
(select max(S.DeliveryDate) 
    from #test S 
    where s.Product = T.Product
        and S.DeliveryDate < T.DeliveryDate

) AS PriorPurchase
FROM #Test T
```

Comment: Do you have indecies on DeliveryDate and Product?

Comment: I am in control of the database so I could create indecies but I would end up recreating them every time I ran this query since new data is added for every run. I am not sure the time impact of creating them and if it would improve overall performance. I have typically done reporting out of SQL but this is one of my first times being in more control of the actual tables.

Comment: If you are adding data every run, then an index may slow you down.  However, looking strictly at the SELECT query, indices will speed up the SELECT significantly.  We have an 8 GB+ database with millions of rows, and a query like the one you posted would run in under a second with the proper indices in place.

Comment: Can you try using an outer apply rather than subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  `LAG()` seems the most appropriate:

```
SELECT T.*,
       LAG(T.DeliveryDate) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Product
                                 ORDER BY T.DeliveryDate
                                ) as PriorPurchase
FROM #Test T;
```

Note this is not exactly the same.  If you have multiple rows with the same delivery date for a given product (this does not occur in the sample data), then `LAG()` is not quite the same.  If you do have such data, then window functions can still be used but the logic is a bit trickier.

Comment: So these seems like what I want, I playing around with it currently. One thing I left out that I am now realizing I am not sure how to implement for partitions is that I have a final column of "successful" that is 1 or 0. I only want the most recent successful delivery date. Is that possible?  
   
  
Since you did solve the initial problem smoothly I am accepting so others can see.

Comment: @SamuelHoward . . . You can just add `where successful = 1`.  Note that this runs the risk of filtering out products that have never had a successful delivery.  Handling such products would make the answer a bit more complicated -- and so be worthy of a new question.

Comment: To be clear you are discussing that I could add that where at the end to remove all unsuccessful shipments correct? There is no (easy) way to remove it from just the Lag portion?

Comment: @SamuelHoward . . . Not in SQL Server.